# how to preserve const correctness across pointers?

Tags: c++, constants

I am trying to have a const operation on a class that is truly const - it does not change data that the class points to.

For example:

```
class Node{
public:
    int val;
};
class V{
public:
    Node * node; //what is the change that is needed here?
    void const_action()const{
        node->val=5; //error wanted here
    }
    void action(){
        node->val=5; //error is not wanted here
    }
};
```

Comment: I know C++ programmers have crystal balls, but have you really given them enough information here to make your question answerable?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Every question can be improved, but IMO it's pretty clear what's being asked here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think this one is OK. I know this is an exception these days.

Comment: See, I *knew* some C++ person would understand what "const conrectness" [sic] meant.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a template to enforce the const correctness on a pointer without changing the meaning or the implementation of your class:

```
    template <typename T>
class PreseveConstPointer
{
    T *t_;
public:
    PreseveConstPointer(T *t = nullptr)
        : t_(t)
    {
    }
    PreseveConstPointer<T> * operator=(T *t)
    {
        t_ = t;
        return this;
    }
    T* operator->()
    {
        return t_;
    }
    T const * operator->() const
    {
        return t_;
    }
    T * data()
    {
        return t_;
    }
};
class Node{
public:
    int val;
};
class V{
public:
    PreseveConstPointer<Node> node;
    V()
    {
        node = new Node;
    }
    ~V()
    {
        if(node.data())
            delete node.data();
    }
    void const_action()const{
        node->val=5; // You will get an error here
    }
    void action(){
        node->val=5; // No error here
    }
};
```

Comment: @yigalirani I tested it before answering :-)

Comment: I can still violate `const`: make a local  `Preserve`, copy the member, and modify through local.  Avoiding this is difficult.  In general reseatable pointers need 2 tiers of `const`, where one is like `const_iterator`.

Comment: @Yakk - Of course you can explicitly violate it if you like. The point is to get warned when you do things unintentionally not when you explicitly want to "cheat" the compiler.

Comment: Except I can easily do that accidentally.  I pass a `const` `Node` to a function.  It innocently copies it to a non-`const` `Node`, and modifies the data in that non-`const` `Node`.  If you block reseating by copy assignment (like `vector`) the above pattern is good.  If you do not, the above pattern is error prone and best avoided.

Comment: @Yakk I think you are wrong. You can't pass Node directly unless you explicitly access the data() method (or do something ugly like Node* n = node.operator->() - You don't do such a thing accidentally.

Comment: Sorry, `V`.  Pass `V` by `const`.  Create a copy of it that is non-`const`.  Write to `Node` .  You have to block copy-by-pointer.  Doing this in `V` is bad, should be responsibility of pointer owning class.  It shoukd either cioy by allocation or block non move copy.

Comment: @Yakk Yes you can create a copy of a const object and make it non const but that was not the question. The question was about preserving the const correctness when accessing a pointer from a const method. This correctness is enforced by the template regardless of whether the instance is const or not. You are talking about a different scenario which you may or may not guard against.

Answer (score 1):

`const` after a function declaration says that the function is not allowed to change any class members (except ones that are marked `mutable`).

Since your code doesn't change any class member, and only changes the object `node` points to, both function will compile.

AFAIK there's no way to prevent this. If you mark the `node` `const`, neither will compile.

Answer (score 1):

**You're confusing `Node* const` for `Node const*`.**

An [unfortunate?] side effect of using indirection here is that `const`ness of the pointer member has nothing to do with the actual `Node` on which you're operating.

If you don't need that member to be a pointer, then this is pleasingly easy:

```
class V
{
public:
    Node node;

    void const_action() const
    {
        node.val = 5; // error here
    }

    void action()
    {
        node.val = 5; // no error here
    }
};
```

However, given its name, I suspect life is not that simple and you are basically out of luck.