# How to call other class' const member function via a std::unique_ptr member

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

While reading about a proposal for adding a const-propagating wrapper to the standard library (doc. no. [N4388](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4388.html)), I bumped into the example given in the paper:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void bar() const
    {
        std::cout << "A::bar (const)" << std::endl;
    }

    void bar()
    {
        std::cout << "A::bar (non-const)" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B
{
    B() : m_ptrA(std::make_unique<A>()) {}

    void foo() const
    {
        std::cout << "B::foo (const)" << std::endl;
        m_ptrA->bar(); // calls A::bar() (non-const)

        // const_cast<const std::unique_ptr<A>>(m_ptrA)->bar(); // how to call the A::bar() const?
    }

    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "B::foo (non-const)" << std::endl;
        m_ptrA->bar();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<A> m_ptrA;
};

int main()
{
    const B const_b;
    const_b.foo();
}
```

which outputs:

> > B::foo (const)
> > A::bar (non-const)

I understand why this happens. Even if the pointer is `const`, the object it points to is non-const, so indeed the non-const member function `A::bar` is called (this is the whole point of the proposal in the paper, to avoid this seemingly awkward situation and propagate `const` via a wrapper). Furthermore, they say that to avoid this situation, once can `const_cast` the pointer `m_ptrA` in `B::foo() const`, so it calls the desired `A::bar() const`.

I tried countless combinations but frankly I don't know how to `const_cast` the `unique_ptr`. Namely, how can I enforce in `B::foo() const` the "right" call to `A::bar() const` via the `m_ptrA`? (see also the comment in the code if it's not entirely clear what I want).

Comment: `static_cast<const Type&>(*ptr).method()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to const-cast the stored pointer, not `unique_ptr`:

```
const_cast<const A*>(m_ptrA.get())->bar();
const_cast<const A&>(*m_ptrA).bar();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed. For some reason I thought I can use a `const_cast` directly on the smart pointer, similar to `static_pointer_cast` for `shared_ptr`. But your solution is probably the only way.

Comment: @vsoftco `const_cast` on the smart pointer changes constness of the smart pointer but the smart pointer's `operator ->` and `operator *` do not preserve constness for the returned object. This mimics how raw pointers behave. If you need const-preserving pointer, you can use [this implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21065654/4538344).